# get actual image path from gallery in android N or above

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to pick image from gallery and upload to the server, but i am not able to get the actual image path from the content uri in android N.

here is my code which i use to get actual image path from the gallery but it only work till android M.

In android N or above it return null

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

how i can achieve this in android N or above. help me !!!

thanks in advance.

Comment: check this will help you https://github.com/maraj91/ImagePickerDemo

Comment: "but it only work till android M" -- it will not work reliably there either. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Use that `InputStream`, either to do the upload or to make a local copy of the content to some file that you control.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you have any sample code ? so that it would be more easy to understand.

Comment: `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri)`